# HornetQ Integrate with Glassfish Using JCA

Tags: glassfish, jms, message, hornetq, jca

how to integrate the hornetq with glassfish using JCA ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's some work to be done in order to integrate HornetQ on glassfish:

This task was open at the time you asked this: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HORNETQ-675

HornetQ is an open source project, and HornetQ developers would welcome anyone willing to help to accomplish this task. HornetQ developers would be supportative of someone trying it.